# How can I use an HTML tag to wrap all elements that follow a specified element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with Vue 2 and Sanity.io and I need a way to surround all elements that comes after a specific element with HTML tag, and then surround this element along with the followed elements with another HTML tag.

let's say every `<h1>` will have multiple paragraphs that follows it and then another `<h1>` and another paragraphs follow it. I want those to be divided with summary and details HTML tags.

For example, I have data coming over from Sanity and it goes like this.

```html
<h1>text</h1>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>

<h1>text</h1>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

I need a way to manipulate the DOM to make it read my data like this

```html
<details>
<summary><h1>text</h1></summary>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
</details>

<details>
<summary><h1>text</h1></summary>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
</details>
```

To clarify more, I'm using [protable-text-to-vue package](https://www.sanity.io/plugins/portable-text-to-vue) which sends back the data as vue components blocks. basically they are coming from sanity in a similar form to the example mentioned above.

Comment: How does the response from `sanity` look like?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I edited the question to add more clarification.

Comment: `blocks` is just a text? if yes  you could replace the tags using string methods

Comment: It's all test yes, some comes as h3 and some comes as paragraphs. Can you provide an example or a source to an example?

Comment: Consider adding a *runnable* [mcve]. Please note codesandbox makes [importing local projects](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) via CLI fairly easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the `mounted()` to call `getElementsByTagName()` :

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Then I looped over each element and wrapped it with `<summary> and <details>` tags.

```js
ele.outerHTML =
                '<details><summary>' +
                ele.outerHTML +
                '</summary></details>'
```

And then I moved all `h1` children inside the `<details>` tags by using `appendChild()`.

```js
let children = document.querySelectorAll(
              `details:nth-child(index) ~ *:not(h1,h1 ~ *)`
)

Array.from(children).map(function(child) {
        document
        .getElementById(`uniqueId`)
        .appendChild(child)
})
```